# theta function help

Tags: number-theory

i need some help with this question

Let $ \theta(z,t)= \sum \limits_{m,n\in\mathbb{z}}e^{-\pi Q_z(m,n)t} $ where  $ Q_z(m,n)=y^{-1}|mz+n|^2. $

and i need to show  $ \theta(z,t) = t^{-1} \theta(z,t^{-1})$
i saw what other people done at  [Calculating a summation of a $\theta$ function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176157/calculating-a-summation-of-a-theta-function)

i quote here the answer of anon

> We have $ Q(m,n):=\frac{1}{y}|mz+n|^2 $. Choose a basis of $\Bbb R^2  $orthonormal w.r.t. Q so that with the base-change matrix U and coordinates $\mathbf{r}=U\mathbf{s}$ we have $Q(U\mathbf{s})=\|\mathbf{s}\|^2$ and therefore
>   \begin{array}{c l}\widehat{e^{-\pi Q(\cdot)}}(\mathbf{m})& = \int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\pi Q(\mathbf{r})t}e^{2\pi i\langle\mathbf{m},\mathbf{r}\rangle}d\mathbf{r} \\ & =\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\pi Q(U\mathbf{s})t}e^{2\pi i \langle\mathbf{m},U\mathbf{s}\rangle}\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial\mathbf{s}}\right|d\mathbf{s} \\ & = \int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\pi \|\mathbf{s}\|^2}e^{2\pi i\langle U^T\mathbf{m},\mathbf{s}\rangle}|\det U|d\mathbf{s} \\ & = e^{-\pi \|U^T \mathbf{m}\|^2}=e^{-\pi Q(\mathbf{m})}.\end{array}

now i try to understand why the t variable disappear in the 3-th equation.
Moreover i know that i need to use Poisson summation formula w.r.t 
$ f(m,n)=e^{-\pi Q(m,n) t} $

help please :)
thank a lot

Comment: if someone need the prove of this is in the book of
Diamond_F.,-A_First_Course_in_Modular_Forms-Springer(2005)
page 149